# É possível acessar a propriedade um objeto dentro dele mesmo?

Tags: javascript, propriedade

```
Cadastro = {
    "descricao" : "Novo usuário",
    "editando" : false
}
```

É possível em tempo de execução eu obter o valor da propriedade "editando" e usa-lo?

Algo como:

```
Cadastro = {
    "descricao" : "Novo usuário",
    "editando" : false,
    "titulo" : "editando" ? "Editar" : "Criar"
}
```

Eu encontrei uma forma mas não é usando a propriedade e sim criando uma variavel no escopo global:

```
window.editando = true;
Cadastro = {
    "descricao" : "Novo usuário",
    "editando" : false,
    "titulo" : (window.editando ? "Editar" : "Novo")
}
```

Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso? O que eu quero é quando o valor da variável mudar o valor do retorno "titulo" também mude.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

code, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
var Cadastro = function (descricao, editando) {
  this.descricao = descricao;
  this.editando = editando;
};

Object.defineProperty(Cadastro.prototype, "titulo", {
  get: function () { return this.editando ? "Editar" : "Criar"; },
  enumerable: true
});

var cadastro1 = new Cadastro("Novo usuário", false);
console.log(cadastro1.titulo); // Criar

var cadastro2 = new Cadastro();
cadastro2.descricao = "Novo perfil";
cadastro2.editando = true;
console.log(cadastro2.titulo); // Editar
```

Depedendo da sua implementação, você pode encontrar alguma dificuldade por causa da combinação de `Object.defineProperty` e `*.prototype`, neste caso defina a propriedade no construtor da "Classe".

```js
var Cadastro = function (descricao, editando) {
  this.descricao = descricao;
  this.editando = editando;

  Object.defineProperty(this, "titulo", this.descriptor.titulo);
};

Cadastro.prototype.descriptor = {};
Cadastro.prototype.descriptor.titulo = {
  get: function () { return this.editando ? "Editar" : "Criar"; },
  enumerable: true
}

var cadastro1 = new Cadastro("Novo Usuario", true);
var cadastro2 = new Cadastro("Novo Perfil", false);

console.log(JSON.stringify(cadastro1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(cadastro2));
```

Comment: Estou fazendo alguns testes, mas creio que a sua resposta é correta para essa situação.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria, muito obrigado! =)

Answer (score 9):

```js
var Cadastro = {
    descricao: "Novo usuário",
    editando: false,
    get titulo() {
        if (this.editando) {
            return "Editar";
        } else {
            return "Criar";
        }
    }
};

console.log(Cadastro.titulo);
Cadastro.editando = true;
console.log(Cadastro.titulo);
```

Answer (score 6):

Com que com uma pequena gambiarra é possível sim.

Utilize uma self-invoking function fazendo e utilize o `this`, assim você referenciará o próprio objeto. Utilizei a propriedade `__init` para poder referênciar o próprio objeto. Daí, como a variável `this` só não fica acessível no contexto de declaração, eu  chamo ela ao fim da declaração do objeto. Para que a variável `Cadastro` importe o valor de declaração do nosso objeto, é necessário retornar o `this` ao final dessa função.

Veja isso como um "construtor" do nosso objeto.

```
Cadastro = {
    "descricao" : "Novo usuário",
    "editando" : false,
    "__init" : function ()
    {
          alert(this.editando)

          this.titulo = this.editando ? "Editar" : "Novo";
          return this;
    }
}.__init()
```

Confira no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwxLajxm/)

Nesse caso, é necessário que o `this` esteja dentro do contexto do objeto que deseja referenciar (no caso a nossa função anônima referencia `Cadastro`). Se você usar o `this` fora de um contexto de um objeto, a referência será `window`.

Outra forma de fazer essa declaração que você precisa seria declarando esse índice `titulo` depois de declarar o objeto. Faça assim:

```
Cadastro = {
    "descricao" : "Novo usuário",
    "editando" : false,
}

Cadastro.titulo = Cadastro.editando ? "Editar" : "Novo";
```

Comment: É possível ao chamar propriedade titulo ele executar a função e verificar novamente o valor da variável? Eu consegui tirando o self-invoking e chamando diretamente

Comment: Se você usou o `this` e funcionou fora, é porque ele está em `window`. `this` fora de um escopo referencia window. Como seu exemplo você criou uma propriedade chamada `editando` em `window`, o `this` vai pegar esse valor de lá.

Comment: Infelizmente a primeira forma que você citou não funciona corretamente: http://i.imgur.com/upB4Muh.png

Comment: Estou verificando aqui, aguarde...

Comment: @c0de com a nova alteração funciona, veja

Comment: Você criou um propriedade que é uma função anônima pegando o valor do contexto atual né? :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, o que acontece com a propriedade `titulo` se a propriedade `editando` for alterada após a inicialização do objeto?

Comment: Sim.... Quando você disse que o  `this` não funcionava é porque estavamos chamando o objeto no contexto de declaração. Mas como eu chamo no final, então ele já é "contato" como declarado

Comment: @TobyMosque eu entendi onde quer chegar, mas o que o AP deixou bem claro é que ele quer declarar um objeto, já com os valores determinados, de acordo com essa propriedade. Então não há necessidade de algo mais complexo

Comment: Na verdade é pra uma página de cadastro o padrão é falso, quando eu setar pra true eu quero que ele retorne a string tratada, mas estamos no caminho.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Dê uma olhada na resposta que eu adicionei! :)

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples e pratica:

```js
Cadastro = {
    descricao: "Novo usuário",
    editando: false,
    titulo: function () {
        return this.editando ? "Editar" : "Novo";
    }
}

// Depois é so chamar quando precisar
console.log(Cadastro.titulo());
Cadastro.editando = true;
console.log(Cadastro.titulo());
```

Comment: Não é prático pois eu tenho que chamar o método `()` e não apenas a propriedade.

Comment: Meu jovem o método acaba virando a própria propriedade, pois ela é definida a partir de uma condição.